# High Power Permanent Magnet DC Motor Controller

Tags: h-bridge, motor-controller, brushed-dc-motor

I am looking for a way to control both the DIRECTION and SPEED (variable speed) of a permanent magnet DC motor, similar to the ones found on mobility scooters. The motor has the following ratings:

- 24VDC
- 18A full load current draw.
- 0.43kW rating.

Initially my idea was to build a basic H-bridge driver using high power MOSFETS and then use PWM to control the switching. However through research I found out that it is actually quite difficult to build as there is a lot to take into account.

What other methods are there for controlling the direction and speed of a DC motor?. Most circuits online seem to be a repeat of one another or are only designed for low power applications.

Comment: Your initial idea is the best for operating from a DC source. A controlled rectifier approach would probably be a little simpler, but that is for AC input. There are much simpler methods using series resistors, but they waste a lot of power.

Comment: It depends what you want to do. If you want to learn how to build an H bridge, then jump right in. A motor load is very forgiving. If you have a scope and patience, you will learn a lot. If however, you want to drive a motor, then buy a motor controller, I used 4QD's for my robot, and I can build H bridges!

Comment: I would love to build an H-bridge from scratch but unfortunately I am short on time at the moment and my knowledge in electronics isnt the best. It would still make a great learning curve though

Comment: If you want to simplify a little bit, you can build a unidirectional speed controller with one MOSFET instead of 4, and use a DPDT switch (or relay or contactor) for reversing. Only flip the switch with the speed set to zero - with a relay you could interlock to make sure of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get you motor running rather than spend months learning how to design a motor controller, there are many off-the-shelf units that have the capabilities you need.  Look into hobby radio-control brushless ESCs from manufacturers like Castle Creations, Turnigy and JETI.  Some of them (intended for r/c cars) have reversing capabilities.  If you want something higher-end than the hobby stuff, there are industrial motion controllers from firms such as Elmo.

If you do want to build one "from scratch", the TI InstaSpin dev kits are a great place to start.  Even the cheap Launchpad + BoostXL-DRV8305 kit will be able to run your motor at a good fraction of its rated power.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement in motor control besides commutation timing, and controls for torque and direction is to decide the cost tradeoff for power losses during stall current.

- This is often 8x the rated current at full load.
- This is peak current when starting/stopping motor at full torque
- Consider that 8x 18A x= 144 A implies the motor DCR = 24C/144 A = 167 mΩ
- Motor losses then start at Pd=I²*DCR = 144²*167mΩ =3.5kW assuming 0 Ω bridge
- Switching Bridge losses then rise with RdsOn and torque reduces.

I prefer to start with a budget of RdsOn =1% of DCR of motor then decide if that suits requirements and budget.

Thus RdsOn= <=1.67mΩ and Ip=144A for x duration.